# OIDC Integration for Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

I am trying to use Cognito User Pool to handle user authentication. I've started down the path of integrating an OIDC provider for login. It is mostly working, thanks to help from a few [SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47815161/cognito-auth-flow-fails-with-already-found-an-entry-for-username-facebook-10155) and [this post](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-cognito-link-user-accounts).

I've gotten to the point where I'm able to link the external user to my internal user, but when I try to login I get "Invalid Provider Name Username combination" error. I noticed that it's because the user id for the external user has capitals in it, but the linked user_id in Cognito is only lowercase.

Example:
External User's Okta id: `abc123DEF`
Internal User's id: `<uuid>` (doesn't matter)
Cognito external user's id: `okta_abc123def`
Internal user's identity list: `[{"userId":"abc123def","providerName":"Okta","providerType":"OIDC","issuer":null,"primary":false,"dateCreated":1640383493683}]`

Has anyone ran into this issue before and figured out a solution? I could solve it if I knew the user's external ID before they sign up since Cognito requires the linking command to be called before the external user is added, but that would require them knowing their internal id and providing it which is too much overhead.

EDIT:

When manually calling the link user command with case-sensitive user id, and then try logging in with the external provider, I get a code back as expected, but no external user is created in Cognito (when there should be) and the code doesn't work to get back tokens.

UPDATE:

The issue was I was not calling the LOGOUT endpoint for the cognito domain so it was using the incorrectly linked auth'd user instead of trying to re-auth through Cognito. Using the suggestion of a custom attribute (which maintains casing) I was able to use the pre sign-up lambda to link the users and it's working for me now. There is still the issue of an error of the user already existing, but I can handle that in my client like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47815161/cognito-auth-flow-fails-with-already-found-an-entry-for-username-facebook-10155) suggests.

Answer (score 0):

We run into the same issue and we resolve it by adding the custom field which stores the original value and when we are linking the user we are using the value from the custom field.

The custom field should be mapped to External User's Okta id.

Comment: Oh gotcha, that makes sense to be able to access it later. However, even when manually calling the link command with the correct ProviderAttributeValue I seem to be running into issues (see edit on post). Anything stand out to you as to what would cause that?

Comment: Not sure If I understand your problem but if you are linking users manually after they signup with oidc then you must have both users already in cognito, 
Standard cognito user from the registration form and external cognito user from OIDC.  Without both users it is impossible to call the link function. So first you need to have both users and then call the link function